# How do I arrange div dropdown behind other div so part of dropdown border gets covered?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm building a simple dropdown menu for an avatar. The problem I'm having is that I want the dropdown menu to cover a portion of the avatar's border, so it looks more seamless. Here's what I mean.

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image]

I probably built my HTML/CSS incorrectly, but I tried adding z-indexes, but it never changed anything. I'm basically trying to make the dropdown menu go behind the avatar button, and set the avatar's bottom border as none, so it looks seamless.

Any ideas what I could do differently?

**HTML**

```
<div class="user">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/avatars/don.jpg" class="image">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header-arrow-inactive.png" class="arrow">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="wrap">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header .user { position:relative; width:37%; padding:0 10px 0 0; height:100%; float:left; text-align:right; }
header .avatar { position:relative; display:inline-block; width:70px; height:50px; margin:19px 0 0 0; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border:1px solid transparent; }
header .avatar img.image { vertical-align:-30px; margin:0 5px 0 10px; }
header .avatar img.arrow { vertical-align:-18px; }
header .avatar:hover { background:#fff; border:1px solid #dcdcdc; border-bottom:none; }
header .avatar:hover .dropdown { display:block; }
header .avatar .dropdown { position:absolute; top:50px; left:-231px; display:none; width:300px; height:200px; background:#fff; border:1px solid #dcdcdc; }
header .avatar .dropdown .wrap { padding:20px; }
header .avatar .dropdown p { margin:0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `border-bottom-style:none;`  on the 'avatar" and  `border-top-style:none;` on your drop-down,or just a negative  `margin-top`.

Answer (score 4):

the HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="user">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/avatars/don.jpg" class="image">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/img/header-arrow-inactive.png" class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="wrap">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.avatar{ border-bottom: 0; z-index: 10:}
.dropdown{z-index:9}
```

and fixed :)

Comment: That works, except now when I hover over the avatar, the dropdown won't appear. My CSS for getting the dropdown to appear is this line, but not sure how I would fix it: header .avatar:hover .dropdown { display:block; }

Comment: Okay, I fixed by doing this: header .avatar:hover + div.dropdown { display:block; }. But now, when I move my cursor away from the avatar area and into the dropdown, the avatar's hover effect goes away. How do I make it stay?

Comment: Id say that the right way to open the dropdown is on click, and not on hover, but anyway. MAke the dropdown visible with div.user:hover, and that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Put "avatar" inside "dropdown" and use a negative `margin-top`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Doesn't give me the result I want. The dropdown portion is still over the avatar portion. I need it to go under. The answer below works, sort of.